# ZeroClipboard/ng-clip hover-state for button inside table issue

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, zeroclipboard

I am using ng-clip which utilizes ZeroClipboard library. But I am having this hover state issue with the button to copy.

On table row hover it does go back to full opacity. But when I go to click button it suddenly removes the hover state and hover state doesn't stay active.

Here is my jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/meetgodhani/yu1t5g2v/. And following is my code.

**CSS**

```
.sample-button
{
    opacity:0.3;
}

.table-hover>tbody>tr:hover>td .sample-button {
  opacity:1;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
angular.module('clip', ['ngClipboard']);

function Main($scope) {
    $scope.copytext = "Copy me !";
}
```

**HTML**

```
<h1> ngClip Example </h1>
<table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Button</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td><a href="#" clip-copy="copytext" class="btn btn-primary sample-button">Button</a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Any idea how to fix it ?

Help would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your solution I think

http://jsfiddle.net/yu1t5g2v/7/

```
onDomready
```

I changed the menu options of JSFiddle.

[image: change here]

I hope it can help. It must be like "document ready" in jQuery.

Comment: Strange same behaviour doesn't work when I use ng-repeat and data is coming using Ajax. Although I load the angular on dom ready.

Comment: I added angular.element(document).ready(function () {} codes did you notice ?